# Cartodb info window not showing variables on map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, infowindow, cartodb

I am setting up a community map that includes the location of some tree pits. The map can be found here http://moabiter-baumscheiben.seedbomb.city/map/. I am using mapbox for the basemap and cartodb to include the layer with the tree pit markers.

I manged to get a custom info window running, but it will not show the variables ( `{{img}}` and `{{name}}` ) from my cartobd database.

I can't find the error. Would be great if someone could help me out.

I included all mapbox and cartodb css and js into the `<head>`

```
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
<script src="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.uncompressed.js"></script>
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.1/mapbox.standalone.js'></script>
```

The is the script for the info window:

```
<script type="infowindow/html" id="infowindow_template">
    <div class="cartodb-popup v2">
        <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
        <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
            <div class="cartodb-popup-header">
                <h1>Baumscheibe</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
                <!-- content.data contains the field info -->
                <h3>Image:</h3> <img src="{{img}}">
                <h3>Gepflegt von: {{name}}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

And this the script for the map layers:

```
<script>
   L.mapbox.accessToken = 'My MapBox access code';

   var southWest = L.latLng(52.510135, 13.284534)
       , northEast = L.latLng(52.559125, 13.400293)
       , bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

   var map = L.map('map', {
       center: [52.5279664, 13.32686126]
       , maxBounds: bounds
       , zoom: 14
       , maxZoom: 20
       , minZoom: 14
   });

   map.fitBounds(bounds);


   var layers = {
       Streets: L.mapbox.tileLayer('svpvertex.ml8nijl4')
       , Imagery: L.mapbox.tileLayer('svpvertex.m0ammo9e')
   };

   layers.Streets.addTo(map);

   //add cartoDB layer, set z-index so it shows up on top
   cartodb.createLayer(map, 'My CartoDB access').addTo(map)
       .on('done', function (layer) {
           layer.setZIndex(5);
           // get sublayer 0 and set the infowindow template
           var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);

           sublayer.infowindow.set('template', $('#infowindow_template').html());
       }).on('error', function () {
           console.log("some error occurred");
       });
</script>
```

Would be great if somebody could help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's an issue with your interactivity.

If you are using the editor remember to switch on the fields you need on the infowindow or set up the custom infowindow so all are available.

If you're using named maps add those fields to the interactivity definition on the template.